# Mapbox GL segmentation fault

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, stdstring, mapbox-gl

I use mapbox-gl-native (https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native).

I have class, for example:

```
class MapboxGL {
public:
 explicit MapboxGL();
 ~MapboxGL();
}
```

In constructor `MapboxGL()` i tried to create an object and set access token:

```
mbgl::DefaultFileSource *fileS = new mbgl::DefaultFIleSource(nullptr);
fileS->setAccessToken("my token");
```

But after `fileS->setAccessToken(..)` i have error:

```
Segmentation fault in mbgl::DefaultFileSource::setAccessToken(..)
```

call stack: function: `std::string::assign(std::string const&)()`

mbgl::DefaultFileSource method:

```
void mbgl::DefaultFileSource::setAccessToken(const std::string& t) { accessToken = t; }
```

What is the problem?

Comment: maybe `fileS` is `NULL` ?

Comment: no, fileS and t is not nullptr, when mbgl::DefaultFileSource::setAccessToken is called

Comment: void mbgl::DefaultFileSource::setAccessToken(const std::string& t) { accessToken = t; }